# hello-jni Sample ndk-build fails

Tags: android, windows, android-ndk

I'm following the instructions [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html#Samples) for hello-jni sample:

There are a few other questions on SO on this, but none have the same message.

My command line:

I have set environmental variable up for `ndkroot`

```
From the project dir>%ndkroot%/ndk-build
Gdbserver : [arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3] libs/armeabi/gdbserver
/usr/bin/sh: -c: line1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
make: *** [libs/armabi/gdbserver] Error 1
```

I have made the build.xml file as instructed and my Android.mk file is untouched, not sure if it should be though:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := hello-jni
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hello-jni.c

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I am using NDK 7b.

Comment: be assure that your ndk path doesn't contain any blank space.

Comment: @hotveryspicy thanks I already saw that problem `%ndkroot%` is `C:\Progra~2\Android\android-ndk-r7b` and just to rule it out completely, took out of prog files and set to `C:\Android\android-ndk-r7b` - no difference

Comment: Progra~2? please show full path

Comment: @hotveryspicy `Progra~2` is the [8.3 name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename) for my `Program files (x86)` folder, but I have now moved it even out of there, see my edited comment above.

Comment: @hotveryspicy no, there's only the one `<project>\jni\hello-jni.c` and it's got plenty in it even though error says that one file has only one line.

Comment: how you build (.so) file, going to project>jni and /ndk/ndk-build?

Comment: @hotveryspicy yes that's right, although I have resolved the problem now, see my answer, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it was a mismatch between the instructions and the NDK version. I had v7b, but the latest is v8b. Once I downloaded v8b, it worked as per the instructions.